# Simple cross-platform OS-based startup/routing script

Tags: bash, shell, cross-platform, polyglot

I am developing an open source [cross platform utility](https://github.com/stephan-nordnes-eriksen/ruby_ship) which contains some wrappers for housekeeping and variable setup based on operating system. This housekeeping is within it's own script and is, for the most part, generated.

For simplicity, and DRYness, I would love to have a single simple startup-script which selected another script to run based on operating system.

In essence this is what I would like:

```
::# Somehow run this on osx/windows/linux +++
switch OSTYPE
when "win32"
   windows_script.bat ARGS
when "linux"
   linux_script.sh ARGS
when "darwin"
   darwin_script.sh ARGS
....
```

That way it would be even less to deal with when making cross platform applications. The value is to not special case which script to run when developing another app

**Is there any way of achieving this without installing external dependencies?**

Comment: You are looking for a script that is legal in both `sh` and `batch` or `sh` and `powershell` or something like that?

Comment: Essentially yes, I guess. I am wondering if there is some way to have a single file be the entry-point for multiple platforms, and then start other scripts based on OS.

Comment: That's the only way I can think of. You need that entry point to be valid in some available interpreter in all three environments so that it could be the only entry point. I would think powershell would be an easier target than batch but I don't really know. You could try searching for sh/batch or sh/powershell polyglots to see if you can find any to get ideas from.

Comment: @EtanReisner Great input! I found this link that totally dose the trick: http://www.stardot.org.uk/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=2564 (linux, windows and ... amiga :D )

Answer (score 2):

I came up with this back in February

```
${0+: \} <#}
exec powershell $(cygpath -m $(realpath $0)) $*
#>
```

It is a way for a PowerShell script to be run from PowerShell or Bash on
Windows. If run from PowerShell you have

```
${0+: \}
```

Which is basically a strangely named variable `0+: \`, most likely empty so a
NOOP. Then you have

```
<#}
exec powershell $(cygpath -m $(realpath $0)) $*
#>
```

Which is a PowerShell block comment, again does nothing, then any code after
that will be run by PowerShell. Now if you run the same script from Bash, you
get

```
${0+: \} <#}
```

Which essentially runs

```
: '}' '<#'
```

Again, a NOOP, Followed by

```
exec powershell $(cygpath -m $(realpath $0)) $*
```

Which will replace the Bash shell with PowerShell, letting the rest of script
run correctly. This is not a complete solution for your problem, but could be a
start.

[Example](http://github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/ba168e4/scripts/screen-buffer.ps1#L1-L3)

Comment: According to my powershell here that is actually a drive specification of `0+` and a path of ` \\`. So yes, I imagine that is quite likely to be `$null`. Nicely done, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

In my use case I just needed some similar variables in separate powershell and bash scripts. I modified Steven's answer and came up with this example:

```
${0+: \} <#}
#only runs in bash and sets these variables in linux
export foo="foovalue"
export bar="barvalue"
export baz="bazvalue"
#only runs in powershell and sets the same variables#>
${0+: \} <#}
##>; $foo="foovalue"
${0+: \} <#}
##>; $bar="barvalue"
${0+: \} <#}
##>; $baz="bazvalue"
```

It reads like machine code, but I am using terraform to template the values on the systems I'll be pushing this to.